# IE is not showing any changes made using Backbone.js until I deleted the temp files and cookies

Tags: internet-explorer, backbone.js

I developed a one page app using Backbone.js and ASP.Net MVC as my backend. Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox but for some strange reason IE isn't showing any changes.

If I make a change in IE it will show up in Chrome and Firefox but not vise-versa. I can even delete data in Chrome or Firefox and it still shows up in IE even though it doesn't exist in the database anymore.

It isn't until I delete my temporary internet files and cookies that I see the correct changes in IE but it's only for that initial GET.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to set cache control headers specifically for IE.. Otherwise it keeps caching all the requests and the script files..

Try setting this in youe global context so that IE does not cache the requests.

```
// Disallow AJAX caching
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up no caching on the controller to enforce on all requests.

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public class MyController { }
```

Google OutputCache MVC and read through the results to understand it better.